# query postgres select does not return results?

Tags: java, postgresql, select

I am developing a java app, and I use resultset. I write this query, it works and I get the results

```
SELECT * 
FROM BD 
WHERE 
    CAST(parent_id AS integer) = " + (Integer.parseInt(arrHeading[0])) + " 
    AND CAST(section AS double precision) = " + Double.parseDouble(arrHeading[1]) + "";
```

`arrHeading` is type `string`, but when I write the query below it does not return any results. `cas` is type `character varying(12)`. I am having trouble because it's a character, and I dont know why I am not getting any result. I tried with the quotes but still does not work. Any ideas?

```
SELECT * 
FROM BD 
WHERE 
    CAST(parent_id AS integer) = " + (Integer.parseInt(arrHeading[0])) + " 
    AND CAST(section AS double precision) = " + Double.parseDouble(arrHeading[1]) + "
    AND cas = '" + arrHeading[2] + "'";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest to first replace arrHeading[2] with the actual value in the query, i.e. hardcode cas=" 'your valiue' " and see if the query returns any result

Comment: I replace with SELECT * FROM BD WHERE CAST(parent_id AS integer)=" + (Integer.parseInt(arrHeading[0])) + " AND CAST(section AS double precision)=" + Double.parseDouble(arrHeading[1])+ "AND cas='" + "B1"+"'"; and I get results

Comment: @bentham - and if you print your query string?

Comment: I get SELECT * FROM BD WHERE CAST(parent_id AS integer)=19 AND CAST(section AS double precision)=1665.0 AND cas='B1
'

Comment: it seems arrHeadin[2] have an extra white space, use arrHeading[2].trim()